# Generation a random number between 50% and 150%

Tags: java, random, range

I have:

```
private Random rng = new Random();

double random = rng.nextDouble(1.5-0.5) + 0.5;
```

Because I want to generate a number between 50% and 150%. However it throws me an error. How do I get a number in that range using the random function?

Comment: "It throws me an error" isn't a helpful description. Please include the exception stack trace in your questions!

Comment: If you fix the error, it will probably work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is: you should read **javadoc**. Meaning: dont **assume** that some library method does something; instead: read the documentation to verify that your assumptions are correct.

In this case, check out [Double.nextDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble()) ... and find:

*Returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed double value between 0.0 and 1.0 from this random number generator's sequence.*

The point is: there is **no** method nextDouble() that takes a double argument! There is only one that goes without any argument; and that method by default returns a value between 0 and 1.

So, simply change your code to call that method without any argument!

Answer (score 1):

That is because `nextDouble` does not receive parameters, and only return a double between 0.0 and 1.0. Use the following:

```
Random rng = new Random();

double max = 1.5;
double min = 0.5;
double random = rng.nextDouble(); // Double between 0.0 and 1.0

double percentage = random*(max-min) + min;
System.out.println(percentage);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read the error in the ide or just look at the java doc you will see clearly the reason...

> method nextDouble() in the type Random is not applicable for the
>   arguments (double)

the random class has no such a method `nextDouble()` that takes a double as argument

BTW why don't you just generate a random integer between 50 and 150... that would make more sense for the implementation you desire...

something like

```
Random rand = new Random();
randomNum = minimum + rand.nextInt((maximum - minimum) + 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like 50% and 100%

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Random rng = new Random();
    double random = rng.nextDouble();

    if (random <= 0.5) {
        System.out.println("50% " + random);
    } else {
        System.out.println("100% " + random);
    }
}
```